# discord.py image "a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make an image manipulation command in discord.py, I want it to get the image an user sends and paste it into another image, but every time it results in `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'"`

Here is my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def procureajuda(ctx):
    pessoa = (ctx.message.attachments[0])
    hm = (pessoa)
    hm = (await hm.save(fp = 'ha.png', seek_begin = False, use_cached = False))
    h = BytesIO (hm)
    hm = Image.open (h)
    template = Image.open ("E:/Projetos/Copper/templates/procure ajuda.png")
    hm = hm.resize ((360,201))
    template.paste (hm, (0,0))
    template.save("pro.png")
    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("pro.png"))
```

I tried getting rid of the BytesIO part (because I did not know what else to do) and it resulted in a different error, something like `'int' object has no attribute 'read'`.

Edit: sorry, forgot the traceback.

```py
Ignoring exception in command procureajuda:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\programas 2\python 3.9\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Projetos\Copper\copper.py", line 78, in procureajuda
    h = BytesIO (hm)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

Comment: What part of the code raises this error?

Comment: sorry for this, forgot about it 
"Ignoring exception in command procureajuda:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\programas 2\python 3.9\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Projetos\Copper\copper.py", line 78, in procureajuda
    h = BytesIO (hm)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'"

Comment: Please post the traceback as part of your question, not as a comment.

Comment: ok, sorry, i was kinda in a hurry because i was going to a place

Comment: Well, what does the `await` line return? If it's an `int`, this error should not be unexpected

Answer (score 0):

discord send support io.BufferedIOBase as parameter .
you can use io.BytesIO try this :

```
@client.command()
async def procureajuda(ctx):
   pessoa = (ctx.message.attachments[0])
   hm = (pessoa)
   hm = (await hm.save(fp = 'ha.png', seek_begin = False, use_cached = False))
   h = BytesIO (hm)
   hm = Image.open (h)
   template = Image.open ("E:/Projetos/Copper/templates/procure ajuda.png")
   hm = hm.resize ((360,201))
   template.paste (hm, (0,0))
   arr = io.BytesIO()
   template.save(arr,"pro.png")
   arr.seek(0)
   await ctx.send(file = discord.File(arr))
```